# Mapping of Disks and underneath "Primary/Logical" Partition(s) by Unix Terminal Prompt Commands and GRUB Prompt Commands (With GRUB Naming Convention)

Tags: partitioning, mount, grub2, fdisk, lubuntu

In Unix *("Ubuntu/lUbuntu")* how do I find mapping for Disk + Logical and/or Primary Partition Information between the  "ls" output at "GNU GRUB Bootloader Prompt (GRUB Prompt) while booting"  and "fdisk -l, mount
(if required , also alongwith superuser privileges)" output at "lUbuntu/Ubuntu terminal prompt"?

Example : Mapping between )(hd[x],msdos[y]) by GRUB ls and /dev/sda[z] by unix terminal commands mount , fdisk and others etc where "x" denotes base disk number , "y" denotes partition/sub-partitions number , "z" denotes partition/sub-partitions number.

P.S. I have used lUbuntu 18.04 Alternative ISO (x64) for installing lUbuntu OS and used "Guided Partitioning" by "Partition Manager" while installing lUbuntu !

Comment: Probably not. There is no guarantee that the drives will be enumerated in the same order. (Sometimes it might be the case, for example when they are all connected one same SATA controller it might, but it is not always the case.) The partition numbers would probably always be the same though.

Comment: @TomYan about sub-partitions ?

Comment: Not really sure (I assume you mean logical partitions which are "subs" of an extended partition), since I tend to avoid extended partition even before I stopped using MBR/DOS partition table, so I don't really know how grub deal with them.